Is there a way to replace keyframes with a specific linear timing function?
For example, I have this animation
@keyframes fade-out-50-in-70 {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  70% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.animate-fade-out-in {
  animation-name: fade-out-50-in-70;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

try to use this linear (linear(0, 0.5 35%, 1 70%);）function to achieve same thing
@keyframes fade-out-in {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.animate-fade-out-in-2 {
  animation-name: fade-out-in;
  animation-timing-function: linear(0, 0.5 35%, 1 70%);
}

But I failed. how can I turn that into success?


div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
@keyframes fade-out-50-in-70 {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  70% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.animate-fade-out-in {
  animation-name: fade-out-50-in-70;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes fade-out-in {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.animate-fade-out-in-2 {
  animation-name: fade-out-in;
  animation-timing-function: linear(0, 0.5 35%, 1 70%);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
<div class="animate-fade-out-in">by @keyframes</div>

<div class="animate-fade-out-in-2">by timing fn</div>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D it's actually the shortest code here.

No HTML. A proper [mcve] is required to make sure nothing else is going on.

I suspect it's the keyframes - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExqgGva

html is not needed here, it's all about CSS animation and timing functions

Well, even though it's purely CSS, I included the snippet. My question is: is it possible to use the linear() function to replace complex structures in keyframes? and i don't know why my linear(0, 0.5 35%, 1 70%) is not work as my expectation...

Make the keyframes easy by using 100% for opacity: 0 then the linear() function should also be easy to define


@keyframes fade-out-50-in-70 {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.animate-fade-out-in {
  animation-name: fade-out-in;
  animation-timing-function: linear(0, 1 50%, 0 70%);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animate-fade-out-50-in-70 {
  animation-name: fade-out-50-in-70;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
<div class="animate-fade-out-in"></div>
<div class="animate-fade-out-50-in-70"></div>




thanks, I understand now. I have another question: could you explain why linear(0, 0.5, 35%, 1, 70%) doesn't work?

@ss-t.c it's a bit trick to explain in comments, I will try to later update the answer with some explanation

Why don't you use cubic-bezier()?


div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

@keyframes fade-out-50-in-70 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animate-fade-out-in {
  animation-name: fade-out-50-in-70;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.35, 1);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes fade-out-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animate-fade-out-in-2 {
  animation-name: fade-out-in;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.35, 1);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
<div class="animate-fade-out-in"></div>



